# OpenMP scoping - seg. fault with shared()

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, openmp

I have the following code:

```
[...]

#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single firstprivate(nodes)
   {

      [...] /* Do some calculation to find out the value of "nodes" */

      double *tForTasks[nodes];

      for(node=0; node < nodes ; node++){

         #pragma omp task private(l, k ,j) shared(tForTasks)
         {
            [...] /* Piece of iterative kernel that writes on tForTasks and on private data structures */
         }
    }
}

[...]
```

and I found out that defining **tForTasks** as shared causes a segmentation fault, but taking **shared(tForTasks)** out of the task declaration works just fine. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

I didn't provide more code because it seems irrelevant for the problem (please let me know if something is needed). I have the segmentation fault for any number of threads between 1 and 16. Without **shared(tForTasks)**, I never have it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try moving the declaration of tForTasks outside the parallel region? Does it have any effect?

Comment: I can't. "nodes" is only known inside the single region. It was edited, BTW.

Comment: I see, but surely you can move also the computation of "nodes" outside the parallel region... The fact is, when the task will run the variable tForTasks might not even exist anymore if the code in the enclosing curly braces has finished running...

Answer (score 1):

The `task` clause is not part of region of single according to OpenMP specs (link?). Thus, it can outlive  the `tForTasks` array and run after its destruction. Thus when you declare it `shared`, tasks can refer to uninitialized or deallocated memory raising segmentation fault. When you omit the `shared` specification, the array is copied to each task as `firstprivate` since it was declared in the parallel region. But in this case a thread will not see the writes to `tForTasks` from other threads.

One solution is to allocate the array dynamically and release it after the tasks completion.